# Working on production database with JPA

Tags: java, database, jpa, stored-procedures, eclipselink

I am working on java application with JPA, I need to access to two databases (the database of my application which is completely new) and an other external databases which is in production.

I need your help for the schema generation database action in Persistence.xml `(<property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="create"/>)`

For my internal database, as I am in developement phase, I am using drop-and-create, but what shoud I use for the other external database ? (I will just use stored procedures of this database and I won't do anyhting else), so using "none" will be enough? Shoud I use or verify other proprietes to make sure that I will not change/delete/add anything oh this external database ?

Thank you very much

Comment: Your question is not 100% clear: while you want probably "test" or run you app in production / release candidate, do you want access production / release candidate environment from you development box?

Comment: During my developement phase (or test phase) of my application, I want to acess to another external database which is in production, I will just call a stored procedure (which will give my data and will not make any change on the database). I hope that I am more clear and thank you very much for your answer

Comment: I see.. Well, whilst accessing production during your dev phase is bad practice, this is not the place to dispute your personal choices, I'd say that even if you want only call store procedures, your JPA stack will try to figure out which is the action to take against the database schema: if your production schema matches the dev one, you can use "verify", if it does not you can use "none" but this might lead to inconsistencies and errors, of course. Bear in mind that both "none" and "verify" won't protect you against accidental writes (unless you connect in read-only mode).

Comment: Thank you very much, when you say "unless you connect in read-only mode", you mean having a read only account ? or it is possible to connect with JPA in read-only ?
And connecting with read-only, I can access to the store procedures ? (these store procedures will not add anything on the DB, just return existing data)

Comment: You need a temporary / server side database read-only mode connection, you have to set it up directly on your database connection (yes, the account). JPA could do it but you have to set your entities as immutable, so after your test you also have to roll-back those changes. As far as I know there is not a "magic" JPA configuration to tell it "this is a read-only connection": JPA focuses on ORM and knows nothing about the underlying database restrictions. I expect you can call stored procedures in read-only mode, but I am not a db admin and not particularly familiar with grants and db auths.